# Julia: How to clear console

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I am using Julia Studio and would like to know the command for clearing the console of text and memory like imports or variables? Something like matlabs "clc" and "clear" commands.

Answer (score 21):

To clear the console, you can go into the shell and run `clear` (or `cls`) from there:

```
julia> ;
shell> clear
```

Comment: That's the elegant way to do that!

Comment: ERROR: IOError: could not spawn `clear`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)

Comment: @CTZStef: your console's equivalent of UNIX's `clear` command must be in your path.  If you are using Windows, you can try `cls`.  What system are you using?

Answer (score 17):

To clear Julia REPL, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Nice to clear the screen, but do not free the memory.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned workspace() provides a fresh Main. One can clear variables (and the screen) with the following:

```
function clear()
    Base.run(`clear`)
    for var in names(Main)
        try
            eval(parse("$var=0"))
        catch e
        end
    end
    gc()
end
```

Variable definitions are permanent but can be nulled. To free types and the like wrap them in modules. For more info see the first two questions [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#How-do-I-delete-an-object-in-memory?-1).

Comment: ``TERM environment variable not set.
failed process: Process(`clear`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]``

Comment: gc() not found. This needs to be updated

Answer (score 2):

can try this:

```
function clc()
    if Sys.iswindows()
        return read(run(`powershell cls`), String)
    elseif Sys.isunix()
        return read(run(`clear`), String)
    elseif Sys.islinux()
        return read(run(`printf "\033c"`), String)
    end
end
```

use like:

```
clc();
```

Comment: In my case, `read(run(`powershell cls`), String)` is great. Thanks!